# React JS command npm is not working on VS Code

Tags: reactjs, node.js, git, npm

I am running my React JS project on VS Code but it gives me following Error, I have tried every possible solution e.g, set the environment variable, uninstalling but the error is not resolving.

```
PS C:\Users\Nimra\Downloads\deployment\react-frontend> node -v
v20.9.0
PS C:\Users\Nimra\Downloads\deployment\react-frontend> npm -v
git: '/c' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
PS C:\Users\Nimra\Downloads\deployment\react-frontend> npm install
git: '/c' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
        gc
```

This is the error I am getting.